# Eureka can not work with docker? What is different between eureka and consul?

Tags: docker

I have three computers, and I develop Eureka feign and eureka client service applications, I published them in docker. The configuretion is above:
1. I published Eureka and feign in different docker containers, bu they are in the same host. The host ip is 192.168.43.132,and I export port 8989 to 1111 for Eureka container, export port 9000 to 2222 for feign 
2. i published eureka client service with docker in another host,the host ip is 192.168.43.134, and I export port 9999 to 9999 for eureka client service
then I can see the service registered in eureka, but I can not visit this server by feign, but I can use browser visit eureka client service directly.
Could anyone tell me why?

I know that Need to tell eureka client running in Docker to use host's IP,so I use configuration eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true or eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true, but they didnt work

Answer (score 0):

you should run docker containers in host mode, default is bridge mode and it assigns internal ip and registers this internal ip with eureka server. So your clients can not access via internal ip.

```
docker run --net=host ...
```